# React Native Android build duplicate error

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-code-push

I have a problem when bundling my android app with Android Studio (with react native). It shows me the following error:

```
[string/CodePushDeploymentKey] /Users/{user}/{app}/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml  
[string/CodePushDeploymentKey] /Users/{user}/{app}/android/app/build/generated/res/resValues/release/values/gradleResValues.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

my  strings.xml file looks pretty normal:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">{appname}</string>
    <string name="appCenterCrashes_whenToSendCrashes" moduleConfig="true" translatable="false">DO_NOT_ASK_JAVASCRIPT</string>
    <string name="appCenterAnalytics_whenToEnableAnalytics" moduleConfig="true" translatable="false">ALWAYS_SEND</string>
    <string moduleConfig="true" name="CodePushDeploymentKey">KEY</string>
</resources>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit:
I solved the problem. I used the multistaging key and I needed to delete the codepushdeployment line in strings.xml